# Basic concepts: Naive Bayes algorithm for classification

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I think I understand Naive Bayes more or less, but I have a few questions regarding its implementation for a simple binary text classification tast.

Let's say that document `D_i` is some subset of the vocabulary `x_1, x_2, ...x_n`

There are two classes `c_i` any document can fall on, and I want to compute `P(c_i|D)` for some input document D which is proportional to `P(D|c_i)P(c_i)`

I have three questions

1. `P(c_i)` is `#docs in c_i/ #total docs` or `#words in c_i/ #total words`
2. Should `P(x_j|c_i)` be the `#times x_j appears in D/ #times x_j appears in c_i`
3. Suppose an `x_j` doesn't exist in the training set, do I give it a probability of 1 so that it doesn't alter the calculations?

For example, let us say that I have a training set of one:

```
training = [("hello world", "good")
            ("bye world", "bad")]
```

so the classes would have

```
good_class = {"hello": 1, "world": 1}
bad_class = {"bye":1, "world:1"}
all = {"hello": 1, "world": 2, "bye":1}
```

so now if I want to compute probability of a test string being good

```
test1 = ["hello", "again"]
p_good = sum(good_class.values())/sum(all.values())
p_hello_good = good_class["hello"]/all["hello"]
p_again_good = 1 # because "again" doesn't exist in our training set

p_test1_good = p_good * p_hello_good * p_again_good
```

Answer (score 1):

As this question is too broad so I can only answer in a limiting way:-

**1st:-** P(c_i) is #docs in c_i/ #total docs or #words in c_i/ #total words

```
P(c_i) = #c_i/#total docs
```

**2nd:-** Should P(x_j|c_i) be the #times x_j appears in D/ #times x_j appears in c_i.
After **@larsmans** noticed..

```
It is exactly occurrence of word in a document
by total number of words in that class in whole dataset.
```

**3rd:-** Suppose an x_j doesn't exist in the training set, do I give it a probability of 1 so that it doesn't alter the calculations?

```
For That we have laplace correction or Additive smoothing. It is applied on
p(x_j|c_i)=(#times x_j appears in D+1)/ (#times x_j +|V|) which will neutralize
the effect not occurring features.
```

Comment: No, P(xⱼ|cᵢ) is the frequency of xⱼ in class cᵢ, divided by the total number of terms in all documents of that class.